# Jquery sortable - which handle was used to do the sorting

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

Here's my sortable list with two handles (handleOne and handleTwo).

On update I would like to know which handle was used to do the sorting. Is that possible?

```
$( "#sortable" ).sortable({

      items: "> .sortableItem",
      handle: ".handleOne, .handleTwo",
      update: function( event, ui ) {

          //Here I want to know which handle was used to do the sorting.
          //Handle one or handle two
      }
});

<ul id="sortable">
    <li class="sortableItem"><div class="handleOne">row 1 cell 1</div> <div class="handleTwo">row 1 cell 2</div></li>
    <li class="sortableItem"><div class="handleOne">row 2 cell 1</div> <div class="handleTwo">row 2 cell 2</div></li>
    <li class="sortableItem"><div class="handleOne">row 3 cell 1</div> <div class="handleTwo">row 3 cell 2</div></li>
</ul>
```

Thank you!

Comment: event.toElement returns the element that was moved, if that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `target` of the `originalEvent` will give you which element was clicked. Like this:

```js
$("#sortable").sortable({

  items: "> .sortableItem",
  handle: ".handleOne, .handleTwo",
  update: function(event, ui) {
    console.log(event.originalEvent.target)

  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<ul id="sortable">
  <li class="sortableItem">
    <div class="handleOne">row 1 cell 1</div>
    <div class="handleTwo">row 1 cell 2</div>
  </li>
  <li class="sortableItem">
    <div class="handleOne">row 2 cell 1</div>
    <div class="handleTwo">row 2 cell 2</div>
  </li>
  <li class="sortableItem">
    <div class="handleOne">row 3 cell 1</div>
    <div class="handleTwo">row 3 cell 2</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That is it! Works in Firefox, Chrome, IE...
 Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This should set handle the class of the element used, either handleOne or handleTwo.

```
var handle = event.toElement.className.split(" ")[0];
```

```js
$( "#sortable" ).sortable({

      items: "> .sortableItem",
      handle: ".handleOne, .handleTwo",
      update: function( event, ui ) {

          //Here I want to know which handle was used to do the sorting.
          //Handle one or handle two
          var handle = event.toElement.className.split(" ")[0];
          $("#result").text(handle);
          
      }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<ul id="sortable">
    <li class="sortableItem"><div class="handleOne">row 1 cell 1</div> <div class="handleTwo">row 1 cell 2</div></li>
    <li class="sortableItem"><div class="handleOne">row 2 cell 1</div> <div class="handleTwo">row 2 cell 2</div></li>
    <li class="sortableItem"><div class="handleOne">row 3 cell 1</div> <div class="handleTwo">row 3 cell 2</div></li>
</ul>
<span id="result"></span>
```

Comment: Hello, this is what I got: TypeError: event.toElement is undefined

Comment: I can't get it to work in any browser other than Chrome, unfortunately.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Thank you anyway!